# Connecting various components

Tags: python, data-structures, graph

I would like to connect various components in a graph-like structure. For example:

```
                -------->-------- C3
                |
   C1 ---> --- C2 ------->------ C4
                |
                ---------->------ C5
```

Where a component can have any number of incoming/outgoing 'connections'. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Component:
    def __init__(self, inbound={}, outbound={}):
        self.inbound = inbound
        self.outbound = outbound
```

What would be an example of how I could write a method and connect all the five components in the graph shown above?

Additionally, how could I then add a 'circular' connection, for example:

```
                -------->-------- C3
                |
   C1 --->----- C2 ----->-------- C4
    |           |
    |           -------->-------- C5 
    ----------<--------------------|
```

(c5 is now connected to c1 as well)

Comment: Can't you just make pairs of `(from, to)` like for example: `(C1, C2), (C2, C3), (C5, C1)`

Comment: You appear to be re-inventing [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/).  Why not just use it?

Comment: @wim -- yes, I know. I'm just looking for how to do this conceptually at a very basic level. I'm not trying to write a library or anything. More for conceptual understanding.

Comment: How are you distinguishing inbound and outbound connections?  Your illustration does not make it obvious that this graph is intended as a directed graph.

Comment: @wim thanks for pointing that out. I've updated this.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware, but the word ["component"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) already has a well-understood meaning in graph theory, and would generally be referring to an undirected graph.  Are you really trying to define a `Component` class, or are you perhaps attempting to define a `Node` class?

Comment: @wim I meant something like a battery or lamp or resistor, and connecting them all together, like a "electrical component". Should I add that to the question?